# Apache returning default server SSL certificate instead of the correct one

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2, ssl-certificate

I have 2 domains (`domain1.example` and `domain2.example`) under the same Ubuntu 14.04 Apache server. Each domain has one SSL certificate.

It happens that, sometimes, when users open `domain2.example` on the browser, they receive the `domain1.example` SSL certificate instead of `domain2.example` certificate. The weird thing is that it happens sometimes, and also, that if I change the `*:443` default server, it starts answering the SSL of the new `*:443` default server.

What do you think is happening? I cannot find the error.

Comment: Which version of Apache? If before 2.3 you need a `NameVirtualHost` directive.

Comment: Are you always testing with the same client/browser ? Clients not supporting the SNI extension would get served by the default Virtual Host (the first appearing one in the configuration, as explained in [SSL with Virtual Hosts Using SNI](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) )

Comment: Apache does not  know which site you want until *after* the ssl certificate has been negotiated with the browser.  So it will serve the first VirtualHost in finds (top to bottom).  Ways around this are: 1) 1 domain == 1 IP == 1 VirtualHost.  Your server must respond to both IP addresses.  2) 1 domain == 1 port.  So both are on the same IP, but on different ports.  3) use SNI like @EugèneAdell proposed.  But that does not work with all clients.

Comment: I have apache 2.4.7